# evaluate a quoted expression Clojure

Tags: variables, clojure

I'm pretty sure this solution is something very simple, but hard to find...
So if I

```
=> (def x '(1 (dec 3) 3))
;user/x
```

How can I evaluate the expression so that

```
=> (***insert function here** x)
;(1 2 3)
```

So far, with `unquote` I've gotten `(1 (dec 3) 3)`, which is x without the quote, not what I want. And I've looked into `` `~x `` which returns the same result. Is there some combination of ~  @ and ` that returns the evaluated function? (I'm throwing around functions here, these are not restrictions)

Please try not to change my original definition of x, if possible.

---

Ok, suppose for this question, the expression was `'(list 1 (dec 3) 3)`
Now how do I retrieve

```
=> (***insert function here** x)
;(1 2 3)
```

Yes, now eval works. Thanks for adding that important piece of input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by mapping `eval` over the list of sequences.

```
core> (def x '(1 (dec 3) 3))                                                                   
core/x                                                                                       
core> x                                                                                        
(1 (dec 3) 3)                                                                                              
core> (map eval x)                                                                             
(1 2 3)                                                                                                    
core>
```

since `(1 2 3)` is not a proper function call we can fix that and then use eval, which would then handle arbitrarily nested  functions.

```
utotestbed.core> (def x '(1 (dec 3) 3))                                                                   
#'autotestbed.core/x                                                                                       
autotestbed.core> (eval (cons 'list x))                                                                    
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: yes, I am aware, but how would I evaluate the expression in terms of x? That is what I seek.

Comment: Well, I guess this works for this example, but not necessarily for any expression... If I had a function inside another function, where the whole expression is quoted, then I would need to map twice.

Comment: The problem with your original expression is that is isn't an evaluable expression, since (1 ...) is an invalid function call - numbers aren't callable in clojure. If you were to quote a valid clojure expression you can evaluate it completely using eval. In other words, you can either use valid clojure expressions, or make up your own semantics, but there's probabl no fail-safe way to determine if an expression is one or the other.